# Efficient fields over arithmetic circuits

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-field, number-theory, circuit

What sort of fields is efficient over an arithmetic circuit?

Efficient meaning that given a field $\mathbb{F}_p$, reduction (modulo) does not require many multiplications and preferably inversion was cheap.

Comment: The size and value of the $p$ determine the answer, otherwise, this question is too broad.

Comment: @kelalaka the size of p would be roughly 256 bits, the field will most likely be derived from an elliptic curve